# Ошибка 0x80070021 при включении приложения в IIS 7.5 в windows 7

Tags: iis

Содержание ошибки:

> Запрашиваемая страница не доступна из-за неверной конфигурации данных для этой страницы.Данный раздел конфигурации не может использоваться на этом пути. Это происходит, когда раздел блокирован на родительском уровне. Блокировка происходит либо по умолчанию (overrideamodedefauld="deny"), либо устанавливается непосредственно при помощи тэга расположения с OverrideMode="deny"   или наследуемым свойством allowOverride#="false".
>
> Файл конфигурации \c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config.
>
> Запрашиваемый адрес http://172.20.6.136/ default.htm
>
> Источник конфигурации       {modules     handlers    remove name="ASP}
>
> Эта ошибка возникает из-за проблем считывания файла конфигурации для веб-сервера или веб-приложения.

Handlers выделено красным цветом. Помогите устранить ошибку.

Comment: Зачем вы привели адрес ошибки? Мы что, имеем дамп вашей памяти, что ли? 80070021 - Ну здесь ошибка, класс! И как это может нам помочь???

Comment: 0x80070021 в данном случае не адрес, а HRESULT, то есть именно код ошибки, по которому можно найти её описание и способы устранения.

Answer (score 3):

Если на машине не установлен ASP.NET, или вообще хоть что-то из фич для Application Development - секция handlers заблокирована в глобальном конфиге, за ненадобностью. Правильным решением в этом случае будет не править конфиг вручную, а доустановить соответствующие фичи:

На серверной операционке:

1. Запустить визард *Add roles and features*.
2. Выбрать ASP.NET в секции `Web Server (IIS)` -> `Web Server` -> `Application Development`.

На клиентской операционке:

1. Открыть визард *Turn Windows features on or off* (он доступен из диалога установки / удаления программ)
2. Выбрать ASP.NET в `Internet Information Services` -> `World Wide Web Services` -> `Application Development Features`

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать этот вариант:

1. В конфиге попробуйте убрать этот элемент, ктр Вы добавили или мешает на работу. прям удалить из сonfig файла сайта.
2. Потом откройте IIS,
3. зайдите в редактор конфигураций(через свой проект)[image: Конфигурация сайта]
4. И перейдите на тот раздел ктр Вам нужен, и нажмите разблокировать с право[image: кнопка разблокировать]
5. Потом нажмите применить(сохранить) и верните изменения в web.config-е => сохранить.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055) есть описание вашей ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо!  Я заменил в файле applicationhost.config все "Deny" на "allow" и ошибка исчезла.